# How to use SPN to connect via SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I've just completed registering our SQL Server 2008 R2 in AD with an SPN.
I'm able to connect using SQLNCLI10.1 via OLEDB with the following keyword :

```
Server SPN=MSSQLSvc/server.domain.local
```

and once connected, the following query verifies that Kerberos is being used :

```
SELECT auth_scheme FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@spid;
```

result:

```
KERBEROS
```

however, i'm unable to figure out, or search the internet for information on, connecting within SSMS using the SPN. Adding the keywords suggested to "Additional Connection Parameters" just results in

```
Keyword not supported: 'serverspn'
Keyword not supported: 'server spn'
```

Is is possible to connect within SSMS using SPN ? If i do so without specifying SPN, the test query returns:

```
NTLM
```

Answer (score 0):

What commands did you use to create the SPNs?

You should have 2 SPNs for the service. 1 for server.domain.local and 1 for port 1433 (or whatever port your service is using).

Here's the examples from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191153.aspx:

```
setspn -A MSSQLSvc/myhost.redmond.microsoft.com:1433 accountname
setspn –A MSSQLSvc/myhost.redmond.microsoft.com accountname
```

Once the SPNs are created, then Windows Authentication should be all that you need to get Kerberos.

To verify what SPNs are created you can use the following:

```
setspn -l accountname
```

Additionally, if the service account has Write servicePrincipalName and Read servicePrincipalName permissions, it will automatically register the SPNs on startup.

See Clint's blog for more info: http://clintboessen.blogspot.com/2010/02/dynamically-set-spns-for-sql-service.html

Comment: The command to create the SPN was `setspn -A MSSQLSvc/server.domain.local SQLDatabase`. I didn't set a specific TCP port, hoping to not limit use of the SPN to TCPIP protocol. I will try the auto-register discussed in the blogpost by giving the SPN permissions to the account, and report back. Thanks

Comment: I removed the manually set SPN :  `setspn -D MSSQLSvc/server.domain.local SQLDatabase`, set the `read/write  servicePrincipalName` permissions using ASDI Edit as described in Clint's blog post, and restarted the server.  I can see the SPNs now set automatically :  `setspn -T * -Q */server.domain.local`  `CN=SQL Engine Account,OU=Service Accounts,OU=Office Network,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL`  `MSSQLSvc/SERVER.DOMAIN.LOCAL`  However, nothing has changed.  The database service is running under a domain account, and I'm connecting as a sysadmin also with a domain account. What am I still missing ?

Comment: It's possible that there are duplicate SPNs (ie there is an SPN associated with the service and a different account). Run setspn -x. This will list duplicate spns. If there are any dupes, use setspn -d to remove them. Additionally, in command prompt, run klist to verify you have the port 1433 kerberos ticket.

Comment: Zero SPNs reported. It does work when the ServerSPN keyword is specified using the Sql Native Client 10 OLEDB. I'll be content for now with executing commands dependant upon delegation using the OLEDB driver. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Zero **duplicate** SPNs reported, that is. At this point, it's not currently worth investing more time on this, since I can execute the necessary processes under OLEDB.

Comment: Did you run klist and look for the port 1433 ticket? If you're not getting the ticket, something is still wrong. Additionally, the ticket can expire, so you may need to close out SSMS, run klist purge, then open SSMS and log back in.

Comment: Make sure you force the connection to use TCP/IP in the options > connection properties of SSMS Connect to Server.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get NTLM it means that the SPN didn't register properly or that one of the accounts isn't on the domain. Otherwise, you should always get a KERBEROS connection. There are couple of things you need in place to ensure to always get a KERBEROS connection.

- Make sure the **login exists on the domain** which SQL Server runs on.
- Make sure that the **login has sufficient** perms on AD, login used for SQL service.
- Manually create an SPN `setspn -S MSSQLSvc/<domain.com> <login>`. This command will check for duplicates before adding an SPN.
- Above steps will ensure that the **SPN is registered** when you restart SQL server.

To verify a successful registration:

- You can check in SSMS `Management -> SQL Server Logs -> Current`.
- You could also run the following command in CMD `setspn -L MSSQLSvc/<domain.com> <login>`

After you have verified that the server SPN registered successfully, you can login with a domain account and run your test command. You should always get KERBEROS after this.